# PDFSharp: Bookmarks added to first page of each PDF end up all linking to first page of combined pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript, pdfsharp

I am using PDFSharp to add a bookmark to page one of a PDF document for a client.  The client is providing multiple PDF documents with varying pages and each PDF is a single bill for a person.  The client asked me to put the account number in a bookmark on the first page so they can combine them together and process a single PDF with many bills using the bookmark as a means to identify the account number.

I successfully created the bookmark using the following code, but when the client combines the files together using Ghostscript, all bookmarks are assigned to page 1 on the combined PDF.  When they combine other PDF's from another system that essentially does the same thing the bookmarks display as desired on the combined file.  I am not sure what they are doing differently to make this work.

How can I get the bookmark to be set correctly so it is maintained when combined?

```
            string file = "c:/test.pdf";
            string accountNumber = "001234";

            using (PdfDocument doc = PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify))
            {               
                PdfPage page = doc.Pages[0];
                doc.Outlines.Add(accountNumber, page);
                doc.Save(file);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Although redundant since the second parameter in Outlines.Add() is setting the destination page, I just needed the following line:

```
outline.DestinationPage = page;
```